# How to only append date to chat, if date is not already displayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a chat program, and right now I am trying to append a div that displays a date. This is easy enough, **HOWEVER**, I only want to append the div with date information to `#chat`, if it is not already appended.

**FURTHERMORE**, since the date information change programmatically, it is not always the same. So it is okay to append multiple divs with date information **if** the information is not the same.

Any ideas of how to do that?

Here's my client-side code. Again, right now it displays the date no matter what.

```js
socket.on("update", function(time){
                var newDate = new Date(time);
                var weekday = new Array(7);
                weekday[1] = "Monday";
                weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
                weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
                weekday[4] = "Thursday";
                weekday[5] = "Friday";
                weekday[6] = "Saturday";
                weekday[7] = "Sunday";
                var day = weekday[newDate.getDay()];
                var hour = newDate.getHours();
                var minutes = newDate.getMinutes();
                $("#chat").append('<div class="update">'+day+" "+hour+"."+minutes+'</div>');     
        });
```

Comment: `if($("#chat").find('.update').length ==0){$("#chat").append('<div class="update">'+day+" "+hour+"."+minutes+'</div>');    }`  check and let me know worked or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it 3 ways, you either check from `.update` or you set a flag:

```
var updated = 0;
socket.on("update", function(time) {
    //....
    if (!updated) {
        $("#chat").append('<div class="update">'+day+" "+hour+"."+minutes+'</div>');
        updated = 1;
    }
}
```

or

```
if (!$('.update').length) {
    $("#chat").append('<div class="update">'+day+" "+hour+"."+minutes+'</div>');
}
```

or you create a hash (I used base64) and check against that hash if you allow multiple insertions but not duplicate one after eachother.

```
var updated = false;
socket.on("update", function(time) {
    //....
    var dateToWrite = day+" "+hour+"."+minutes;
    var hash = btoa(dateToWrite);
    if (!updated || updated !== hash) {
        $("#chat").append('<div class="update">' + dateToWrite + '</div>');
        updated = hash;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this also work with what I have written in "**furthermore**"?

Comment: then you can check if it's equal, go for second option and check `$('.update')` value or create a hash, I'll make you an 3'rd option :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all - array starts from 0, not 1. Second thing - I'd rename it to `weekdays` (instead of `weekday`) since it's list of them. Third thing - it's better to create array as one call - `weekdays = [ 'monday', 'tuesday' ...]`. Fourth thing - I don't know your chat window structure but you can get `$('#chat')` and it returns it and it's childs. So then get last child element or easier since you use jQuery you can call by css `$('#chat .msg:last-child')` which means get inside id chat find class msg and get it's last occurence. Then check if it contains date already or not.

edit: Sorry, just noticed that you want it for whole chat window. Then - just get `$('#chat .update').text()` and check if there's a date.

Comment: Hi @Mort, could you specify how you would remake the function with an array as one call?

Comment: https://codepen.io/kWeglinski/pen/RVOKmV answer was too long for a comment hence the codepen.

Comment: Can different dates still be appended? Or does your code only allow for one date info?

Comment: this one only adds date if it doesn't exist inside your #chat. Otherwise it checks for existence and leaves without changes. If you want more date info you need to provide yourself more validation. I'm getting a feeling that you should start reading docs for jQuery and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `.update` has inner text.

```
if($(".update").innerText != ''){
  //append
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check first div has date or not by using following code:

```
if(!$("#chat").find('.update').length) {
    $("#chat").append('<div class="update">'+day+" "+hour+"."+minutes+'</div>');
}
```

Just replace the above code with your

```
$("#chat").append('<div class="update">'+day+" "+hour+"."+minutes+'</div>');
```

Thanks